# Firing different variables on windows resize javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on some thing like this, where i am trying to integrate windows re-size function as i require different values for defaults variable on windows re-size so that it calculates the different background position of image but its not happening. can any one help me on how to change the values of defaults variable on different screen sizes.

```
    var flipCounter = function(d, options){
    // Default values
    var defaults = {
    value: 0,
    inc: 1,
    pace: 1000,
    auto: true,
    tFH: 78,
    bFH: 128,
    fW: 106,
    bOffset: 780
};

$(window).resize(function (d, options) {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 1000) {
        defaults = $.extend(defaults, {
            tFH: 39,
            bFH: 64,
            fW: 53,
            bOffset: 390
        });
    }
});

    var o = options || {},
    doc = window.document,
    divId = typeof d !== 'undefined' && d !== '' ? d : 'flip-counter',
    div = doc.getElementById(divId);

    for (var opt in defaults) o[opt] = (opt in o) ? o[opt] : defaults[opt];

    var digitsOld = [], digitsNew = [], subStart, subEnd, x, y, nextCount = null, newDigit, newComma,
    best = {
        q: null,
        pace: 0,
        inc: 0
    };

    /**
     * Sets the value of the counter and animates the digits to new value.
     * 
     * Example: myCounter.setValue(500); would set the value of the counter to 500,
     * no matter what value it was previously.
     *
     * @param {int} n
     *   New counter value
     */
    this.setValue = function(n){
        if (isNumber(n)){
            x = o.value;
            y = n;
            o.value = n;
            digitCheck(x,y);
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Sets the increment for the counter. Does NOT animate digits.
     */
    this.setIncrement = function(n){
        o.inc = isNumber(n) ? n : defaults.inc;
        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Sets the pace of the counter. Only affects counter when auto == true.
     *
     * @param {int} n
     *   New pace for counter in milliseconds
     */
    this.setPace = function(n){
        o.pace = isNumber(n) ? n : defaults.pace;
        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Sets counter to auto-incrememnt (true) or not (false).
     *
     * @param {bool} a
     *   Should counter auto-increment, true or false
     */
    this.setAuto = function(a){
        if (a && ! o.atuo){
            o.auto = true;
            doCount();
        }
        if (! a && o.auto){
            if (nextCount) clearNext();
            o.auto = false;
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Increments counter by one animation based on set 'inc' value.
     */
    this.step = function(){
        if (! o.auto) doCount();
        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Adds a number to the counter value, not affecting the 'inc' or 'pace' of the counter.
     *
     * @param {int} n
     *   Number to add to counter value
     */
    this.add = function(n){
        if (isNumber(n)){
            x = o.value;
            o.value += n;
            y = o.value;
            digitCheck(x,y);
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Subtracts a number from the counter value, not affecting the 'inc' or 'pace' of the counter.
     *
     * @param {int} n
     *   Number to subtract from counter value
     */
    this.subtract = function(n){
        if (isNumber(n)){
            x = o.value;
            o.value -= n;
            if (o.value >= 0){
                y = o.value;
            }
            else{
                y = "0";
                o.value = 0;
            }
            digitCheck(x,y);
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Increments counter to given value, animating by current pace and increment.
     *
     * @param {int} n
     *   Number to increment to
     * @param {int} t (optional)
     *   Time duration in seconds - makes increment a 'smart' increment
     * @param {int} p (optional)
     *   Desired pace for counter if 'smart' increment
     */
    this.incrementTo = function(n, t, p){
        if (nextCount) clearNext();

        // Smart increment
        if (typeof t != 'undefined'){
            var time = isNumber(t) ? t * 1000 : 10000,
            pace = typeof p != 'undefined' && isNumber(p) ? p : o.pace,
            diff = typeof n != 'undefined' && isNumber(n) ? n - o.value : 0,
            cycles, inc, check, i = 0;
            best.q = null;

            // Initial best guess
            pace = (time / diff > pace) ? Math.round((time / diff) / 10) * 10 : pace;
            cycles = Math.floor(time / pace);
            inc = Math.floor(diff / cycles);

            check = checkSmartValues(diff, cycles, inc, pace, time);

            if (diff > 0){
                while (check.result === false && i < 100){              
                    pace += 10;
                    cycles = Math.floor(time / pace);
                    inc = Math.floor(diff / cycles);

                    check = checkSmartValues(diff, cycles, inc, pace, time);                    
                    i++;
                }

                if (i == 100){
                    // Could not find optimal settings, use best found so far
                    o.inc = best.inc;
                    o.pace = best.pace;
                }
                else{
                    // Optimal settings found, use those
                    o.inc = inc;
                    o.pace = pace;
                }

                doIncrement(n, true, cycles);
            }

        }
        // Regular increment
        else{
            doIncrement(n);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Gets current value of counter.
     */
    this.getValue = function(){
        return o.value;
    }

    /**
     * Stops all running increments.
     */
    this.stop = function(){
        if (nextCount) clearNext();
        return this;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    function doCount(){
        x = o.value;
        o.value += o.inc;
        y = o.value;
        digitCheck(x,y);
        if (o.auto === true) nextCount = setTimeout(doCount, o.pace);
    }

    function doIncrement(n, s, c){
        var val = o.value,
        smart = (typeof s == 'undefined') ? false : s,
        cycles = (typeof c == 'undefined') ? 1 : c;

        if (smart === true) cycles--;

        if (val != n){
            x = o.value,
            o.auto = true;

            if (val + o.inc <= n && cycles != 0) val += o.inc
            else val = n;

            o.value = val;
            y = o.value;

            digitCheck(x,y);
            nextCount = setTimeout(function(){doIncrement(n, smart, cycles)}, o.pace);
        }
        else o.auto = false;
    }

    function digitCheck(x,y){
        digitsOld = splitToArray(x);
        digitsNew = splitToArray(y);
        var diff,
        xlen = digitsOld.length,
        ylen = digitsNew.length;
        if (ylen > xlen){
            diff = ylen - xlen;
            while (diff > 0){
                addDigit(ylen - diff + 1, digitsNew[ylen - diff]);
                diff--;
            }
        }
        if (ylen < xlen){
            diff = xlen - ylen;
            while (diff > 0){
                removeDigit(xlen - diff);
                diff--;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < xlen; i++){
            if (digitsNew[i] != digitsOld[i]){
                animateDigit(i, digitsOld[i], digitsNew[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function animateDigit(n, oldDigit, newDigit){
        var speed, step = 0, w, a,
        bp = [
            '-' + o.fW + 'px -' + (oldDigit * o.tFH) + 'px',
            (o.fW * -2) + 'px -' + (oldDigit * o.tFH) + 'px',
            '0 -' + (newDigit * o.tFH) + 'px',
            '-' + o.fW + 'px -' + (oldDigit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px',
            (o.fW * -2) + 'px -' + (newDigit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px',
            (o.fW * -3) + 'px -' + (newDigit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px',
            '0 -' + (newDigit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px'
        ];

        if (o.auto === true && o.pace <= 300){
            switch (n){
                case 0:
                    speed = o.pace/6;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    speed = o.pace/5;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    speed = o.pace/4;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    speed = o.pace/3;
                    break;
                default:
                    speed = o.pace/1.5;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            speed = 80;
        }
        // Cap on slowest animation can go
        speed = (speed > 80) ? 80 : speed;

        function animate(){
            if (step < 7){
                w = step < 3 ? 't' : 'b';
                a = doc.getElementById(divId + "_" + w + "_d" + n);
                if (a) a.style.backgroundPosition = bp[step];
                step++;
                if (step != 3) setTimeout(animate, speed);
                else animate();
            }
        }

        animate();
    }

    // Creates array of digits for easier manipulation
    function splitToArray(input){
        return input.toString().split("").reverse();
    }

    // Adds new digit
    function addDigit(len, digit){
        var li = Number(len) - 1;
        newDigit = doc.createElement("ul");
        newDigit.className = 'cd';
        newDigit.id = divId + '_d' + li;
        newDigit.innerHTML = '<li class="t" id="' + divId + '_t_d' + li + '"></li><li class="b" id="' + divId + '_b_d' + li + '"></li>';

        if (li % 3 == 0){
            newComma = doc.createElement("ul");
            newComma.className = 'cd';
            newComma.innerHTML = '<li class="s"></li>';
            div.insertBefore(newComma, div.firstChild);
        }

        div.insertBefore(newDigit, div.firstChild);
        doc.getElementById(divId + "_t_d" + li).style.backgroundPosition = '0 -' + (digit * o.tFH) + 'px';
        doc.getElementById(divId + "_b_d" + li).style.backgroundPosition = '0 -' + (digit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px';
    }

    // Removes digit
    function removeDigit(id){
        var remove = doc.getElementById(divId + "_d" + id);
        div.removeChild(remove);

        // Check for leading comma
        var first = div.firstChild.firstChild;
        if ((" " + first.className + " ").indexOf(" s ") > -1 ){
            remove = first.parentNode;
            div.removeChild(remove);
        }
    }

    // Sets the correct digits on load
    function initialDigitCheck(init){
        // Creates the right number of digits
        var initial = init.toString(),
        count = initial.length,
        bit = 1, i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
            newDigit = doc.createElement("ul");
            newDigit.className = 'cd';
            newDigit.id = divId + '_d' + i;
            newDigit.innerHTML = newDigit.innerHTML = '<li class="t" id="' + divId + '_t_d' + i + '"></li><li class="b" id="' + divId + '_b_d' + i + '"></li>';
            div.insertBefore(newDigit, div.firstChild);
            if (bit != (count) && bit % 3 == 0){
                newComma = doc.createElement("ul");
                newComma.className = 'cd';
                newComma.innerHTML = '<li class="s"></li>';
                div.insertBefore(newComma, div.firstChild);
            }
            bit++;
        }
        // Sets them to the right number
        var digits = splitToArray(initial);
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
            doc.getElementById(divId + "_t_d" + i).style.backgroundPosition = '0 -' + (digits[i] * o.tFH) + 'px';
            doc.getElementById(divId + "_b_d" + i).style.backgroundPosition = '0 -' + (digits[i] * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px';
        }
        // Do first animation
        if (o.auto === true) nextCount = setTimeout(doCount, o.pace);
    }

    // Checks values for smart increment and creates debug text
    function checkSmartValues(diff, cycles, inc, pace, time){
        var r = {result: true}, q;
        // Test conditions, all must pass to continue:
        // 1: Unrounded inc value needs to be at least 1
        r.cond1 = (diff / cycles >= 1) ? true : false;
        // 2: Don't want to overshoot the target number
        r.cond2 = (cycles * inc <= diff) ? true : false;
        // 3: Want to be within 10 of the target number
        r.cond3 = (Math.abs(cycles * inc - diff) <= 10) ? true : false;
        // 4: Total time should be within 100ms of target time.
        r.cond4 = (Math.abs(cycles * pace - time) <= 100) ? true : false;
        // 5: Calculated time should not be over target time
        r.cond5 = (cycles * pace <= time) ? true : false;

        // Keep track of 'good enough' values in case can't find best one within 100 loops
        if (r.cond1 && r.cond2 && r.cond4 && r.cond5){
            q = Math.abs(diff - (cycles * inc)) + Math.abs(cycles * pace - time);
            if (best.q === null) best.q = q;
            if (q <= best.q){
                best.pace = pace;
                best.inc = inc;
            }
        }

        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            if (r['cond' + i] === false){
                r.result = false;
            }           
        }
        return r;
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844
    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

    function clearNext(){
        clearTimeout(nextCount);
        nextCount = null;
    }

    // Start it up
    initialDigitCheck(o.value);
};
```

Comment: Your problem is you are defining another local variable defaults inside the event handler.

Comment: It's not clear how/when/to_what you wish to pass `d` and `options`. An event handler takes the event object, typically e, as its argument - it will not automagically accept `d` and `options`.

Comment: And, do I understand correctly that `flipCounter()` is written to be called with the `new` operator - ie it's a constructor? If so, then by convention it should have an initial capital, `FlipCounter()` to make it instantly recognisable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaults = {
    value: 0,
    inc: 1,
    pace: 1000,
    auto: true,
    tFH: 78,
    bFH: 128,
    fW: 106,
    bOffset: 780
};

$(window).resize(function (d, options) {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 1000) {
        defaults = $.extend(defaults, {
            tFH: 39,
            bFH: 64,
            fW: 53,
            bOffset: 390
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: still not working... i am providing you the full script...at the bottom of script there is a function called addDigit where it is calculating the background position of sprite image using the values that we we provide in defaults variable.. now i want to make it responsive by changing those default values to fit in different screens

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

You are right to use [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). Just needs a little more thought.

I would write something like this :

```
var FlipCounter = function(d, options) {
    var sizeData = {
        large: {
            tFH: 78,
            bFH: 128,
            fW: 106,
            bOffset: 780
        },
        small: {
            tFH: 39,
            bFH: 64,
            fW: 53,
            bOffset: 390
        }
    };

    var defaults = {
            value: 0,
            inc: 1,
            pace: 1000,
            auto: true
        },
        o = {},
        doc = window.document,
        divId = d || 'flip-counter',
        div = doc.getElementById(divId);

    $(window).resize(function (e) {
        var sizeObj = ($(window).width() <= 1000) ? sizeData.small: sizeData.large;
        $.extend(defaults, sizeObj);
        $.extend(o, defaults, options || {});
    }).resize();

    ...
    ...
    ...

};
```